# Hiding .php extensions in URL not working

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to make it possible to hide the PHP extension on my website so for example, if I go to http://code-up.nl/contact, the http://code-up.nl/contact.php file will be loaded instead. I have several domains on my server. In the root of the website (located at /var/www/code-up.nl) I have the following .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ $1.php [L]
```

And in my apache virtual hosts file, I've put AllowOverride to All:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    ServerName code-up.nl
    ServerAlias www.code-up.nl
    DocumentRoot /var/www/code-up.nl

    <Directory />
            Options FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride All
    </Directory>

    <Directory /var/www/code-up.nl/>
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
            AllowOverride All
            Order allow,deny
            allow from all
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

    # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
    # alert, emerg.
    LogLevel warn

    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

I think everything is right but I still get an error 404 when I go to http://code-up.nl/contact. I've searched for a solution and tried many things but it just won't work. Can anyone help with this?

Comment: mod_rewrite is installed and enabled. I checked it in the output of my phpinfo()

Comment: `RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php [L]`

Answer (score 3):

Try this in your .htaccess under DOCUMENT_ROOT:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# To externally redirect /dir/foo.php to /dir/foo
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R,L,NC]

## To internally redirect /dir/foo to /dir/foo.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}.php [L]
```

Comment: It's working now! But I don't exactly understand what was causing the problem exactly. Could you explain this? Many thanks!

Comment: I will not explain how a .htaccess work, but in this case, you have just to externally redirect all *.php to *, and internally redirect * to *.php for get the good page... and not a 404